# Xamarin Forms Android Sample App - Xamarin.Forms NuGet 2.5.0.91635

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for an Android sample app that runs and compiles, and uses the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package 2.5.0.91635. It must be made in Visual Studio. Does anyone have one?

Edit: as per the answer below, this is how to create a new project with the latest NuGet packages:

[image]

File -> New Project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need anything other than an Empty Xamarin Forms Android app using 2.5.0.91635. If that is sufficient here is an app that compiles and runs on the emulator

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag4_g2yE9YzjjMEOR7OG0z_DtfbGXw

Comment: That is fantastic! It works. How did you create that?

Comment: Just created a new cross platform app in VS 2017 for Windows then updated Xamarin Forms to the latest version.

Comment: Ah! Got it. That's what threw me. I was looking for a Xamarin Forms app, but it just says Xamarin. My bad. Thanks.